# Optaplanner - CVRP - returning to depot mid trip

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing

My problem is a modification of the [**Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem (CVRP)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem#VRP_variants) that will eventually include **time windows** as well.

Since *time windows* are already built into the examples, it shouldn't be too hard for me to figure them out. However, I need to change one of the *core constraints* of the *CVRP* examples, and I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

#### My Model

In the system I'm trying to model, a `Vehicle` can leave its `Depot`, go to several different `Customers`, and load up on material. However, where my model differs from the examples is that the `Vehicle` can visit any `Depot` mid-chain to deposit its current load.

#### Issues

I've been going over the [documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html) trying to figure out how to do this, and my basic understanding so far is that I'd have to change the definition of `Depot` (maybe by implementing `Standstill`) to be able to be part of the chain of places the vehicle visits, and/or maybe just integrate `Depot` into `Customer` with some kind of special rule that a visit to a `Depot` empties the vehicle instead of increasing the demand.

I've also been looking at *shadow variables* and *variable listeners*, but I don't know if that's the right way to go. It's all a little confusing.

Can anyone offer some tips or advice, or point me in the right direction as to where to start before I dig myself too far into a hole?

Comment: Rename the class Vehicle to VehicleTrip, so 1 vehicle can do mutiple trips? If you have timewindows, then connect each VehicleTrip to the previous trip (fixed in advance). Give each vehicle 3 trips or so.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet If I did that, I would still need some way to connect them, and I'm not sure how to get the solver to go about taking that into consideration. How would I link each VehicleTrip's endtime to the starttime of another? Again, I'm thinking a variable listener, but I don't fully understand those yet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the link to mentioned `documentation`. Maybe some [example] or _visual sketched model_ could show your attempt and give us a base to start guiding you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Geoffrey's suggestion, rename your `Vehicle` class to `VehicleTrip` and let it point to the previous **and the next** trip by giving it a value `previousVehicleTrip` and `nextVehicleTrip`, and give it a variable start time and end time (code examples in Kotlin):

```
class VehicleTrip(
    ...,
    var startTime: LocalDateTime? = null,
    var endTime: LocalDateTime? = null,
    val previousVehicleTrip?: VehicleTrip = null,
    val nextVehicleTrip?: VehicleTrip = null
) : Standstill {
    ...
}
```

You can set these values when initiating your `VehicleTrips`. When you get a `StackOverFlowError` based on the `VehicleTrip.hashCode()`, simply override the `hashCode()` function of the `VehicleTrip` class. (Maybe someone has a better suggestion for dealing with this?)

#### Updating the shadow variables.

In your `Customer` class, you should have a variable `arrivalTime` (like in the CVRPTW example) which is a custom shadow variable. In the listener class of this variable you usually only update the arrival time of a vehicle at a customer, and the arrival times of the customers that come next in this trip. Now, you also need to update all the times of the trips that come after the trip your current customer is in.

For example, you might have two trips `VT1` and `VT2`, and three customers `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`. When changing from

```
VT1 - C1 - VT2 - C2 - C3
```

to

```
VT1 - C2 - C1 - VT2 - C3
```

the things you want updated are (in order)

1. `C2.arrivalTime`
2. `C1.arrivalTime`
3. `VT1.endTime`
4. `VT2.startTime`
5. `C3.arrivalTime`
6. `VT2.endTime`

Notice that in the `TimeWindowedCustomer` example, the variable listener only does steps 1. and 2., so we have to add steps 3. until 6.

To do this, start by adding `@CustomShadowVariable` annotations to the start and end times of `VehicleTrip` (and don't forget to mark `VehicleTrip` as a planning entity), which uses the same variable listener class as the time windowed customer:

```
class VehicleTrip(
   ...,
   @CustomShadowVariable(
        variableListenerRef = PlanningVariableReference(
            entityClass = TimeWindowedCustomer::class, 
            variableName = "arrivalTime"
        ))
   var startTime: LocalDateTime? = null,
   ...
) : Standstill {
    ...
}
```

Now in the `ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener` class, you can add steps 3. until 6. similar to how steps 1. and 2. are implemented. Make sure that you keep the order of updating these variables, and that you notify the `ScoreDirector` when changing a variable with the `beforeVariableChanged()` and `afterVariableChanged()` methods.